# Помогите с тестом на Классы и наследование в Python

Tags: python

Классы и наследование

Как правило задачи про классы не носят вычислительный характер. Обычно нужно написать классы, которые отвечают определенным интерфейсам. Насколько удобны эти интерфейсы и как сильно связаны классы между собой, определит легкость их использования в будущих программах.

Предположим есть данные о разных автомобилях и спецтехнике. Данные представлены в виде таблицы с характеристиками. Вся техника разделена на три вида: спецтехника, легковые и грузовые автомобили. Обратите внимание на то, что некоторые характеристики присущи только определенному виду техники. Например, у легковых автомобилей есть характеристика «кол-во пассажирских мест», а у грузовых автомобилей — габариты кузова: «длина», «ширина» и «высота».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам необходимо создать свою иерархию классов для данных, которые описаны в таблице. Классы должны называться CarBase (базовый класс для всех типов машин), Car (легковые автомобили), Truck (грузовые автомобили) и SpecMachine (спецтехника). Все объекты имеют обязательные атрибуты:

- car_type, значение типа объекта и может принимать одно из значений: «car», «truck», «spec_machine».
- photo_file_name, имя файла с изображением машины, допустимы названия файлов изображений с расширением из списка: «.jpg», «.jpeg», «.png», «.gif»
- brand, марка производителя машины
- carrying, грузоподъемность

В базовом классе CarBase нужно реализовать метод get_photo_file_ext для получения расширения файла изображения. Расширение файла можно получить при помощи os.path.splitext.

Для грузового автомобиля необходимо в конструкторе класса определить атрибуты: body_length, body_width, body_height, отвечающие соответственно за габариты кузова — длину, ширину и высоту. Габариты передаются в параметре body_whl (строка, в которой размеры разделены латинской буквой «x»). Обратите внимание на то, что характеристики кузова должны быть вещественными числами и характеристики кузова могут быть не валидными (например, пустая строка). В таком случае всем атрибутам, отвечающим за габариты кузова, присваивается значение равное нулю.

Также для класса грузового автомобиля необходимо реализовать метод get_body_volume, возвращающий объем кузова.

В классе Car должен быть определен атрибут passenger_seats_count (количество пассажирских мест), а в классе SpecMachine — extra (дополнительное описание машины).

Полная информация о атрибутах классов приведена в таблице ниже, где 1 - означает, что атрибут обязателен для объекта, 0 - атрибут должен отсутствовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что у каждого объекта из иерархии должен быть свой набор атрибутов и методов. Например, у класса легковой автомобиль не должно быть метода get_body_volume в отличие от класса грузового автомобиля. Имена атрибутов и методов должны совпадать с теми, что описаны выше.

Далее вам необходимо реализовать функцию get_car_list, на вход которой подается имя файла в формате csv. Файл содержит данные, аналогичные строкам из таблицы. Вам необходимо прочитать этот файл построчно при помощи модуля стандартной библиотеки csv. Затем проанализировать строки на валидность и создать список объектов с автомобилями и специальной техникой. Функция должна возвращать список объектов.

Вы можете использовать для отладки работы функции get_car_list следующий csv-файл:

cars_week3.csv

Первая строка в исходном файле — это заголовок csv, который содержит имена колонок. Нужно пропустить первую строку из исходного файла. Обратите внимание на то, что в некоторых строках исходного файла , данные могут быть заполнены некорректно, например, отсутствовать обязательные поля или иметь не валидное значение. В таком случае нужно проигнорировать подобные строки и не создавать объекты. Строки с пустым или не валидным значением для body_whl игнорироваться не должны.  Вы можете использовать стандартный механизм обработки исключений в процессе чтения, валидации и создания объектов из строк csv-файла. Проверьте работу вашего кода с входным файлом, прежде чем загружать задание для оценки.

Пример кода, демонстрирующего чтение csv файла:

```
import csv

with open(csv_filename) as csv_fd:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)  # пропускаем заголовок
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Ниже приведен шаблон кода для выполнения задания.

```
class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        pass


class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        pass


class Truck(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, body_whl):
        pass


class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, extra):
        pass


def get_car_list(csv_filename):
    car_list = []
    return car_list

Несколько примеров работы:

>>> from solution import *
>>> car = Car('Bugatti Veyron', 'bugatti.png', '0.312', '2')
>>> print(car.car_type, car.brand, car.photo_file_name, car.carrying,
... car.passenger_seats_count, sep='\n')
car
Bugatti Veyron
bugatti.png
0.312
2
>>> truck = Truck('Nissan', 'nissan.jpeg', '1.5', '3.92x2.09x1.87')
>>> print(truck.car_type, truck.brand, truck.photo_file_name, truck.body_length,
... truck.body_width, truck.body_height, sep='\n')
truck
Nissan
nissan.jpeg
3.92
2.09
1.87
>>> spec_machine = SpecMachine('Komatsu-D355', 'd355.jpg', '93', 'pipelayer specs')
>>> print(spec_machine.car_type, spec_machine.brand, spec_machine.carrying,
... spec_machine.photo_file_name, spec_machine.extra, sep='\n')
spec_machine
Komatsu-D355
93.0
d355.jpg
pipelayer specs
>>> spec_machine.get_photo_file_ext()
'.jpg'
>>> cars = get_car_list('cars_week3.csv')
>>> len(cars)
4
>>> for car in cars:
...     print(type(car))
... 
<class 'solution.Car'>
<class 'solution.Truck'>
<class 'solution.Truck'>
<class 'solution.Car'>
>>> cars[0].passenger_seats_count
4
>>> cars[1].get_body_volume()
60.0
>>>
```

В итоге я отправил на проверку такой код:

```
import csv
import sys
import os.path


class CarBase:
    """Базовый класс с общими методами и атрибутами"""

    # индексы полей, которые соответствуют колонкам в исходном csv-файле
    csv_car_type = 0
    csv_brand = 1
    csv_passenger_seats_count = 2
    csv_photo_file_name = 3
    csv_body_whl = 4
    csv_carrying = 5
    csv_extra = 6

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.carrying = float(carrying)

    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)
        return ext


class Car(CarBase):
    """Класс легковой автомобиль"""

    car_type = 'car'

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.passenger_seats_count = int(passenger_seats_count)

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, row):
        return cls(
            row[cls.csv_brand],
            row[cls.csv_photo_file_name],
            row[cls.csv_carrying],
            row[cls.csv_passenger_seats_count],
        )


class Truck(CarBase):
    """Класс грузовой автомобиль"""

    car_type = 'truck'

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, body_whl):
        super().__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        # обрабатываем поле body_whl
        try:
            length, width, height = (float(c) for c in body_whl.split('x', 2))
        except ValueError:
            length, width, height = .0, .0, .0

        self.body_length = length
        self.body_width = width
        self.body_height = height

    def get_body_volume(self):
        return self.body_width * self.body_height * self.body_length

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, row):
        return cls(
            row[cls.csv_brand],
            row[cls.csv_photo_file_name],
            row[cls.csv_carrying],
            row[cls.csv_body_whl],
        )


class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    """Класс спецтехника"""

    car_type = 'spec_machine'

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, extra):
        super().__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.extra = extra

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, row):
        return cls(
            row[cls.csv_brand],
            row[cls.csv_photo_file_name],
            row[cls.csv_carrying],
            row[cls.csv_extra],
        )


def get_car_list(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename) as csv_fd:
        # создаем объект csv.reader для чтения csv-файла
        reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')

        # пропускаем заголовок csv
        next(reader)

        # это наш список, который будем возвращать
        car_list = []

        # объявим словарь, ключи которого - тип автомобиля (car_type),
        # а значения - класс, объект которого будем создавать
        create_strategy = {
            car_class.car_type: car_class for car_class in (Car, Truck, SpecMachine)
        }

        # обрабатываем csv-файл построчно
        for row in reader:
            try:
                # определяем тип автомобиля
                car_type = row[CarBase.csv_car_type]
            except IndexError:
                # если не хватает колонок в csv - игнорируем строку
                continue

            try:
                # получаем класс, объект которого нужно создать
                # и добавить в итоговый список car_list
                car_class = create_strategy[car_type]
            except KeyError:
                # если car_type не извесен, просто игнорируем csv-строку
                continue

            try:
                # создаем и добавляем объект в car_list
                car_list.append(car_class.instance(row))
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                # если данные некорректны, то игнорируем их
                pass

    return car_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_car_list(sys.argv[1]))(None)
```

После проверки мне выдало следующее:

Total tests: 165. Tests failed: 3, Errors: 0. Total time: 1.128.
Failed test - test_21.
assert [, ...] == []
Left contains 18 more items, first extra item:
Use -v to get the full diff
E   AssertionError: Тест 21.3. Вызов функции get_car_list на файле, содержащем только невалидные данные, должен возвращать пустой список. Первый элемент списка, возвращенного функцией get_car_list, имеет атрибуты: car_type: 'car', brand: '', carrying: 2.5, photo_file_name: 'f5.jpeg', passenger_seats_count: 4.

Answer (score 1):

Показываю свое решение

```
import csv
import sys
import os.path


class CarBase:
    """Базовый класс с общими методами и атрибутами"""

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        # проверка что аргументы не являются пустой строкой
        if not all(i != '' for i in (brand, photo_file_name, carrying)):
            raise ValueError

        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.carrying = float(carrying)
        # вызов метода для проверки расширения файла изображения
        self.ext = self.get_photo_file_ext()

    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)
        if ext not in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif']:
            raise ValueError
        return ext


class Car(CarBase):
    """Класс легковой автомобиль"""

    car_type = 'car'

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.passenger_seats_count = int(passenger_seats_count)


class Truck(CarBase):
    """Класс грузовой автомобиль"""

    car_type = 'truck'

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, body_whl):
        super().__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        # обрабатываем поле body_whl
        try:
            length, width, height = (float(c) for c in body_whl.split('x', 2))
        except ValueError:
            length, width, height = .0, .0, .0

        self.body_length = length
        self.body_width = width
        self.body_height = height

    def get_body_volume(self):
        return self.body_width * self.body_height * self.body_length


class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    """Класс спецтехника"""

    car_type = 'spec_machine'

    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, extra):
        super().__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        # проверка что аргумент extra не является пустой строкой
        if extra == '':
            raise ValueError
        self.extra = extra


def get_car_list(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8') as csv_fd:
        # создаем объект csv.reader для чтения csv-файла
        reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')

        # пропускаем заголовок csv
        next(reader)

        # это наш список, который будем возвращать
        car_list = []

        # объявим словарь, ключи которого - тип автомобиля (car_type),
        # а значения - функция, создающая экземпляр нужного класса
        car_types = {
            'car': lambda x: Car(x[1], x[3], x[5], x[2]),
            'truck': lambda x: Truck(x[1], x[3], x[5], x[4]),
            'spec_machine': lambda x: SpecMachine(x[1], x[3], x[5], x[6])}

        # обрабатываем csv-файл построчно
        for row in reader:
            try:
                car_type = row[0]
                # если тип машины в словаре - создаем экземпляр класса
                if car_type in car_types:
                    car_list.append(car_types[car_type](row))
            # при возникновении ошибки - пропускаем строку
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                pass

    return car_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_car_list(sys.argv[1]))
```